# When using Android Worker beginUniqueWork ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP:: How can you detect when subsequent enqueues don't start work

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My current Android Application employs

```
archWorkerRuntimeVersion = '2.3.0-beta02'

api "androidx.work:work-runtime:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
api "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
```

I start work as OneTimeRequests as follows:-

```
        val initialWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(InitialWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()
        val taskOneWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TaskOneWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()
        val taskTwoWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TaskTwoWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()
        val taskThreeWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TaskThreeWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()
        val taskFourWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TaskFourWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()
        val finalWorkerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FinalWorker::class.java).addTag(NUMERIC_WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${System.nanoTime()}").build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            .beginUniqueWork(NUMERIC_UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, initialWorkerRequest)
            .then(listOf(taskOneWorkerRequest, taskTwoWorkerRequest))
            .then(taskThreeWorkerRequest)
            .then(taskFourWorkerRequest)
            .then(finalWorkerRequest)
            .enqueue()
```

My users can attempt to start this work multiple times, however as I am using `beginUniqueWork` with `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` only one instance of the work is started.

I observer the worker via LiveData for ID as follows:

```
  WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(initialWorkerRequest.id).apply {
                observeForever { workInfo ->
                    if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
    }
```

This approach adds an observer every time my user attempts to start the work, even when no work is actually started

```
1). Is this an issue?
2). Is there any way I can detect when using `beginUniqueWork` with `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` does not result in work being started?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not add observer if some uniqueWork with same uniqueWorkName is already running and is not SUCCEEDED.

Suppose i have a demo() method like below and UploadWorker does nothing other then waiting for 10 seconds:

```
  private fun demo() {
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .build()

    val uploadWorkRequest =
        OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        .enqueueUniqueWork("Hello", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, uploadWorkRequest)

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWorkRequest.id).apply {
        observeForever { workInfo ->
            Log.i("LOGWORKSTATUS", workInfo.id.toString() + " " + workInfo.state.name)

        }
    }
}
```

So if i call the above function multiple times within 10 seconds , it will only print the Log statement only once.Only if u call demo() function after 10 seconds it will print another Log statement.

You can also use getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData() to verify that never more than one Work is running.